# bash tr extra operand on redirect to another file

Tags: bash, tr

I have a small script that downloads a value from a web page.
Before anyone looses their mind because I am not using an HTML parser, besides the headers, the  whole web page only has 3 lines of text between one pair of pre tags. I am just after the number values - that is it.

```
</head><body><pre>
sym
---
12300
</pre></body></html>
```

This is the script :

```
#!/bin/bash
wget -O foocounthtml.txt  "http://foopage" 
tr -d "\n" foocounthtml.txt > foocountnonewlines.txt
```

Anyhow the tr command is throwing an error.

```
tr: extra operand ‘foocounthtml.txt’
Only one string may be given when deleting without squeezing repeats.
Try 'tr --help' for more information.
```

Yes, I could use sed for inplace modification with the -i tag. However I am perplexed by this tr error. Redirecting tr output works fine from command line, but not in a script.

Comment: Use `<` to redirect the input file on stdin instead of passing its name.

Comment: That is: `tr -d '\n' <foocounthtml.txt >foocountnonewlines.txt`

Comment: Because `tr` thinks that foocount.html is an option/argument.

Comment: BTW, your script could be `wget -O - 'http://foopage' | tr -d '\n' >foocountnonewlines.txt`, or if you really want to keep the interim file, `wget -O - 'http://foopage' | tee foocounthtml.txt | tr -d '\n' >foocountnonewlines.txt`. Any of those pipelines will make things a little faster, because they let `tr` run while `wget` is still operating, instead of making it a one-after-the-other thing.

Comment: `tr` is one of the few commands that cannot read or write files itself. `tr` relies on the help of the shell (here `bash`) and uses stdin and stdout from `bash` to read and write.

Answer (score 2):

The 'tr' command operates on SETs of text rather than files. From the man page:

```
NAME
   tr - translate or delete characters

SYNOPSIS
    tr [OPTION]... SET1 [SET2]

DESCRIPTION
    Translate, squeeze, and/or delete characters from standard input, writing to standard output.

...

    SETs are specified as strings of characters.  Most represent themselves.  Interpreted sequences are:
```

So `tr` is expecting the actual content you want to operate on rather than the target file. You can simply pipe the files contents to `tr` for the resuts you  want

```sh
cat foocounthtml.txt | tr -d "\n" > foocountnonewlines.txt
```

or as @CHarlesDUffy points out, it would be faster to read directly from the file:

```sh
tr -d "\n" < foocounthtml.txt > foocountnonewlines.txt
```

Comment: Don't use `cat ... |` unnecessarily; it's slower than letting `tr` read from the file directly.

Comment: ...and while it's only _slightly_ slower for `tr`, it can be _vastly_ slower for tools like `tail` or `sort` or `wc -c` that benefit from random access when they have a seekable file descriptor. Better to be in the habit of passing real file handles around whenever possible, instead of pipes that can only be read, once, front-to-back.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy `tr` doesn't read from files directly, thats what I'm attempting to get across. I handles the contests of the files directory rather than reading form the file itself. See the usage  line, it speicifies one ore more `SET`s rather than a file so you need to feed the contets to it directly in some whay, such as using the `cat` command.

Comment: `foo <file` connects `file` to the stdin of `foo`. It's a real file handle -- with access to all the normal calls like `seek()` and `tell()` rather than just `read()` -- even if it's on FD 0.

Comment: ...I _do_ completely understand your point that `tr` expects its input to be connected to stdin, but that's not a good reason to make it be connected via a FIFO reading from the stdout of a copy of the separate program `cat`, instead of just connecting it straight to the input file, as a redirection with `<` would do.

Comment: BTW, if you like the left-to-right structure, `<foocounthtml.txt tr -d '\n' >foocountnonewlines.txt` retains it, even with no `|` or `cat` in sight.

Comment: Oh, fair enough I misunderstood your point, I'll update  my answer. Thanks for the input!

Comment: (BTW, I do suggest single quotes for `'\n'` -- they're a little more explicit that the backslash reaches `tr` as literal text, whereas the rules for double-quoted strings sometimes have backslashes consumed by the parser, as in cases like `"\\"` or `"\""`).